# Cross-browser alternative of Date.now() and innerHTML security?

Tags: javascript, validation, submit, duration

I have PHP form validation rules working but I also don't want valid but nonsense real human-being spams. Currently, the JavaScript code below gets the timestamp of the page loaded time and the timestamp of the form submission. If the difference is below 18 seconds it asks 'are you superman?' in an alert box and doesn't allow the user to submit until time arrives.

**Q1 )** `Date.now()` is supported by ie9+. Which alternative function achieves the same work in ie7+ ? (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#Browser_compatibility)

**Q2 )** Does this function itself has security gap? I ask because I suspect of `document.getElementById('PageLoadTime').innerHTML = pageloaded` code if variable `pageloaded` could be edited from outside!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>trial</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>user page loading timestamp: <span id="PageLoadTime"></span></div>
    <div>form submission timestamp: <span id="submitTime"></span></div>
    <div>time difference: <span id="difference"></span></div>

    <script>
        var pageloaded = Date.now();    
        document.getElementById('PageLoadTime').innerHTML = pageloaded;

        function GetSubmitTime(pageloaded) {
        document.getElementById('submitTime').innerHTML = Date.now();
        document.getElementById('difference').innerHTML = Math.floor((Date.now() -  pageloaded)/1000);
        if ( Math.floor((Date.now() -  pageloaded)/1000) < 18 )
            {
                if(event.preventDefault){
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }else{
                            event.returnValue = false; // for IE as dont support preventDefault;
                        }
                        alert("are you superman?");
            }
        }

    </script>

    <form method="post" action="my home page" onsubmit="GetSubmitTime(pageloaded)">
    <input type="text" id="e1" name="n1">

    <input type="submit" value="send" > 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.now()` returns what `new Date().getTime()` returns, and the latter has been supported essentially forever.

Setting the `innerHTML` of an element to a system timestamp is not a security risk.

Nothing in the client is safe from user tampering. Anybody using your form can force the form to be submitted without any regard to your time check.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your first question. Put the following at the top of your JavaScript and you can use `Date.now()` even on  IE < IE9.

```
Date.now = Date.now || function() { return +new Date; };

console.log(Date.now()); // 1406206659562
```

Furthermore, your code in general is fine, though the security on the client side is always relative.